# Import in HIVE from MySql using Sqoop

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/i --username root --password root --table Student --hive-home /user/hive/warehouse --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table databasename.tablename -m 1
```

Not showing any data in Hive table name 'tab1' and database is 'abc'. MySQL database name `inst` and table name `stu`.

Comment: have you tried with `--connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/inst`

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/inst --username root --password root --table stu --hive-home /user/hive/warehouse --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table abc.tab12 -m 1 ...fir bhi run nhi hua

Answer (score 0):

In the command you should use --warehouse-dir or --target-dir instead of --hive-home. If not provided any of above two parameters the location of the data will take in default location. But --hive-home is used to overwrite the $HIVE_HOME value. So it will look for hive in that path which you mentioned, but there is no hive in it and there is no dir for default location from that location you mentioned. So no data will be stored only table was created. So try without --Hive-home. Your command will be

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/i --username root --password root --table Student --target-dir /path/in/hdfs --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table databasename.tablename